# Python - Read JSON - TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to read a json that I created in the script myself. When I try to access one of his "attributes" after reading the following error appears:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "index.py", line 74, in <module>
        print(json_leitura['items'])
    TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

the same error occurs when I put it  `print(json_leitura['topico'])` at the end.

I don't know if the creation of the JSON file is correct. I don't know if the reading is correct. When I try to trigger the "print" command or assign the value to a variable. The error described above always occurs.

**Code**

```
import requests
import json

def requisicao_api(url):
    resposta = requests.get(url)
    if resposta.status_code == 200:
        return resposta.json()
    else:
        return resposta.status_code

def requisicao_url(url):
    dados_api = requisicao_api(url)
    return dados_api

def monta_lista_repos_topico(topico):
    lista_registros = []
    
    # Percorre os 1000 primeiros registros, ou seja, 10 páginas de 100 registros.
    for x in range(1,2):
        urlprincipal = f'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic:{str(topico)}&sort=stars&order=desc&page={str(x)}&per_page=1'

        print(urlprincipal)

        dados_api = requisicao_url(urlprincipal)    

        if type(dados_api) is int: # Caso ocorra algum erro. Sai do loop e retorna lista vazia
            print("Erro: " + str(dados_api))
            break
        else:
            #Pega os repositórios no item e insere em uma lista
            print("Página: " + str(x))

            print(dados_api['items'])
            items = dados_api['items']
    
            for i in range(len(items)):
                lista_registros.append(items[i])
        
    return(lista_registros)


def gravar_arquivo_json(nome_arquivo, dados):
    with open(nome_arquivo, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(dados, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2, sort_keys=False, separators=(',' , ':'))

def ler_arquivo_json(nome_arquivo):
    with open(nome_arquivo, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        return json.load(f)

#================================================================================#
# MAIN                                                                           #
#================================================================================#

# Alterar essas duas variáveis
topico       = "open-data"
nome_arquivo = "open-data.json"

# Monta uma lista com os repositórios do tópico
lista_repos = monta_lista_repos_topico(topico)

# Monta um json com tópico e lista de repositórios
registro_json           = {}
registro_json['topico'] = topico
registro_json['items']  = lista_repos
arquivo_json            = json.dumps(registro_json, indent=2, sort_keys=False)

print(arquivo_json)

# Grava json
gravar_arquivo_json(nome_arquivo, arquivo_json)

# Leitura json
json_leitura = ler_arquivo_json(nome_arquivo)

print(json_leitura['items'])
```

**JSON**

```
"{\n  \"topico\": \"open-data\",\n  \"items\": [\n    {\n      \"id\": 62087567,\n      \"node_id\": \"MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnk2MjA4NzU2Nw==\",\n      \"name\": \"serenata-de-amor\",\n      \"full_name\": \"okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor\",\n      \"private\": false,\n      \"owner\": {\n        \"login\": \"okfn-brasil\",\n        \"id\": 1666382,\n        \"node_id\": \"MDEyOk9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbjE2NjYzODI=\",\n        \"avatar_url\": \"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1666382?v=4\",\n        \"gravatar_id\": \"\",\n        \"url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/okfn-brasil\",\n        \"html_url\": \"https://github.com/okfn-brasil\",\n        \"followers_url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/okfn-brasil/followers\",\n        \"following_url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/okfn-brasil/following{/other_user}\",\n        \"gists_url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/okfn-brasil/gists{/gist_id}\",\n        \"starred_url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/okfn-brasil/starred{/owner}{/repo}\",\n        \"subscriptions_url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/okfn-brasil/subscriptions\",\n        \"organizations_url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/okfn-brasil/orgs\",\n        \"repos_url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/okfn-brasil/repos\",\n        \"events_url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/okfn-brasil/events{/privacy}\",\n        \"received_events_url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/okfn-brasil/received_events\",\n        \"type\": \"Organization\",\n        \"site_admin\": false\n      },\n      \"html_url\": \"https://github.com/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor\",\n      \"description\": \"\\ud83d\\udd75 Artificial Intelligence for social control of public administration\",\n      \"fork\": false,\n      \"url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor\",\n      \"forks_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/forks\",\n      \"keys_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/keys{/key_id}\",\n      \"collaborators_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/collaborators{/collaborator}\",\n      \"teams_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/teams\",\n      \"hooks_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/hooks\",\n      \"issue_events_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/issues/events{/number}\",\n      \"events_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/events\",\n      \"assignees_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/assignees{/user}\",\n      \"branches_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/branches{/branch}\",\n      \"tags_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/tags\",\n      \"blobs_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/git/blobs{/sha}\",\n      \"git_tags_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/git/tags{/sha}\",\n      \"git_refs_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/git/refs{/sha}\",\n      \"trees_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/git/trees{/sha}\",\n      \"statuses_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/statuses/{sha}\",\n      \"languages_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/languages\",\n      \"stargazers_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/stargazers\",\n      \"contributors_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/contributors\",\n      \"subscribers_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/subscribers\",\n      \"subscription_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/subscription\",\n      \"commits_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/commits{/sha}\",\n      \"git_commits_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/git/commits{/sha}\",\n      \"comments_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/comments{/number}\",\n      \"issue_comment_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/issues/comments{/number}\",\n      \"contents_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/contents/{+path}\",\n      \"compare_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/compare/{base}...{head}\",\n      \"merges_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/merges\",\n      \"archive_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/{archive_format}{/ref}\",\n      \"downloads_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/downloads\",\n      \"issues_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/issues{/number}\",\n      \"pulls_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/pulls{/number}\",\n      \"milestones_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/milestones{/number}\",\n      \"notifications_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/notifications{?since,all,participating}\",\n      \"labels_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/labels{/name}\",\n      \"releases_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/releases{/id}\",\n      \"deployments_url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor/deployments\",\n      \"created_at\": \"2016-06-27T20:55:11Z\",\n      \"updated_at\": \"2021-06-03T02:10:38Z\",\n      \"pushed_at\": \"2021-06-01T17:54:22Z\",\n      \"git_url\": \"git://github.com/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor.git\",\n      \"ssh_url\": \"git@github.com:okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor.git\",\n      \"clone_url\": \"https://github.com/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor.git\",\n      \"svn_url\": \"https://github.com/okfn-brasil/serenata-de-amor\",\n      \"homepage\": \"https://serenata.ai/en\",\n      \"size\": 71008,\n      \"stargazers_count\": 4283,\n      \"watchers_count\": 4283,\n      \"language\": \"Python\",\n      \"has_issues\": true,\n      \"has_projects\": false,\n      \"has_downloads\": true,\n      \"has_wiki\": false,\n      \"has_pages\": false,\n      \"forks_count\": 696,\n      \"mirror_url\": null,\n      \"archived\": false,\n      \"disabled\": false,\n      \"open_issues_count\": 66,\n      \"license\": {\n        \"key\": \"mit\",\n        \"name\": \"MIT License\",\n        \"spdx_id\": \"MIT\",\n        \"url\": \"https://api.github.com/licenses/mit\",\n        \"node_id\": \"MDc6TGljZW5zZTEz\"\n      },\n      \"forks\": 696,\n      \"open_issues\": 66,\n      \"watchers\": 4283,\n      \"default_branch\": \"main\",\n      \"score\": 1.0\n    }\n  ]\n}"
```

Comment: json_leitura  is just a string, can you try printing it on its own so we can verify? I imagine there's a problem with loading the json or the contents of the fole

Comment: `requisicao_api` should raise an exception rather than returning the non-200 status code. Don't make it the caller's responsibility to check if the function returns an integer status code or a JSON response (which may be impossible, since `reposta.json` could, in theory, return 204, since `json.loads('"204"') == 204`).

Comment: Why does `requisicao_url` exist? It's a wrapper around `requisicao_api` with no purpose of its own.

Comment: @Anthony1223

I added JSON.

Can you check it please ?

I couldn't make the line breaks (\n) in the file itself. However, when I print json, it looks cool, making the line breaks (\n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line

`arquivo_json = json.dumps(registro_json, indent=2, sort_keys=False)`

Which according to the documentation, `json.dumps` "Serializes obj to a JSON formatted str according to [conversion table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#py-to-json-table)"

In effect, the problem is that you are serializing the `registro_json` object twice, and ending up with a `str`. If you remove the offending line and directly pass `registro_json` to the `gravar_arquivo_json` function, everything should work.

Updated code:

```py
import requests
import json

def requisicao_api(url):
    resposta = requests.get(url)
    if resposta.status_code == 200:
        return resposta.json()
    else:
        return resposta.status_code

def requisicao_url(url):
    dados_api = requisicao_api(url)
    return dados_api

def monta_lista_repos_topico(topico):
    lista_registros = []
    
    # Percorre os 1000 primeiros registros, ou seja, 10 páginas de 100 registros.
    for x in range(1,2):
        urlprincipal = f'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic:{str(topico)}&sort=stars&order=desc&page={str(x)}&per_page=1'

        print(urlprincipal)

        dados_api = requisicao_url(urlprincipal)    

        if type(dados_api) is int: # Caso ocorra algum erro. Sai do loop e retorna lista vazia
            print("Erro: " + str(dados_api))
            break
        else:
            #Pega os repositórios no item e insere em uma lista
            print("Página: " + str(x))

            print(dados_api['items'])
            items = dados_api['items']
    
            for i in range(len(items)):
                lista_registros.append(items[i])
        
    return(lista_registros)


def gravar_arquivo_json(nome_arquivo, dados):
    with open(nome_arquivo, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(dados, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2, sort_keys=False, separators=(',' , ':'))

def ler_arquivo_json(nome_arquivo):
    with open(nome_arquivo, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        return json.load(f)

#================================================================================#
# MAIN                                                                           #
#================================================================================#

# Alterar essas duas variáveis
topico       = "open-data"
nome_arquivo = "open-data.json"

# Monta uma lista com os repositórios do tópico
lista_repos = monta_lista_repos_topico(topico)

# Monta um json com tópico e lista de repositórios
registro_json           = {}
registro_json['topico'] = topico
registro_json['items']  = lista_repos

# Grava json
gravar_arquivo_json(nome_arquivo, registro_json)

# Leitura json
json_leitura = ler_arquivo_json(nome_arquivo)

print(json_leitura['items'])
```